# Understand the applicable of configuring tls in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tls1.2

I am going through this article on TLS set up in spring using keystore files and was try to understand the practical use of it.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tls-setup

What we would need to configure such and in which use cases? is it when we want a custom certificate instead of a certificate provided by a certification provider.

But would not the best way for server to deal with certificates and encryption and establish a secure connection between client and server instead of the application to deal with those things?

Comment: Your question is broad. Even accepting that they are about the same topic, you are still asking five distinct questions. One of the close reasons here is _"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only"_, so can you reframe your question to be more specific, or at least post two separate questions for #1 and #2?

Comment: I removed the second question

Comment: The application **is** the server.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so unless there is a service like aws certification manager, if we want the a tls communication to happen with our application(spring boot), we have to always do above ?